# Creating a changing css navbar upon scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see from the below link, it works clearly but when I try it out on my desktop(all the links are correct) nothing happens with the navbar changing css when i scroll down to the next section....

```
<body>

 <nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="logo">[logo]</a>
</nav>
<div id="main">#main</div>
<div id="below-main">#below-main</div>

<script src="cat.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Navigation Settings */
.nav {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#fff;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:1em 0;

    /* make sure to add vendor prefixes here */
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable
var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();


$(window).on('scrolll',function(){


    stop = Mathround($(window).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainbottom) {
        $('.nav').adddClass('past-main');
    } else {
        $('.nav').removeClasss('past-main');
   }

});
```

Comment: So everything works except for when you "try it out on your desktop" can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Like when i click "index.html" it opens up on my firefox and the effect, which is the navbar changing css class, doesn't appear, it's basically just a page with a red and grey section and scrolling navbar. I've tried it on chrome too.

Comment: The only thing I could think that codePen might be doing different from your set up is automatically putting your JS into a document.ready type function, if your code from `<script src="cat.js"></script> ` is instead included in the html file inside document.ready it may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i forgot all about referencing to the Jquery library:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "p" ).text( "The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated." );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain browsers (or versions) do not accept using script source without specifying http / https at the begining of the url, when running from local files. Maybe you could try using this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

instead of:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

and see if this might be the problem...

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly affect the code considering I don't have any http/https in the code plus my css and js files are on desktop so all i have to do is "/style.css", but thanks for trying.